# How to Place question mark and exclameratry marks in plist Permissions

Tags: ios, permissions, info.plist

Can any one please let me know How to use "" and ! symbols in plist permission values.

for example:

> NSCameraUsageDescription : "This app uses camera recognition for what
>   you "Record" with your camera!" like this.

I placed the same in .plist file, message showing correctly for the permission but camera feature is not working.

Please suggest me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should work, Probably it is some issue with the code or something else. Can you share more information, code or something that can help in isolating the issue? What makes you think `""` and `!` in permission text are causing the issue?

Comment: yes @VivekMolkar... I thought special symbols causes the issue. any way I'll try once more.